# Using "or" inside a GraphQL query "where" object

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have a GraphQL query (powered by a Strapi backend) that looks like this:

```
query posts($where: JSON!) {
  posts(
    sort: "createdAt:DESC",
    where: $where
  ) {
    id
    title
  }
  postsConnection(where: $where) {
    aggregate{
      count
    }
  }
}
```

It retrieves a bunch of documents that fulfil a condition as passed to it via a `$where` object.

```
{
    "where": {
        "isPublished": true,
        "body_contains": "lorem",
        "title_contains": "lorem"
    }
}
```

In the above example, the condition states that both `body` and `title` fields should contain the term `lorem`. This works. However, this is an AND operation. It only retrieves documents that are `true` on `isPublished`, contain `lorem` in `body`, and contain `lorem` in `title`.

What I want is documents that are `true` on `isPublished`, and contain `lorem` in either `body`, or `title`, or both.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

The query can be run at https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql using the following HTTP headers:

```
{
  "Authorization": "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkOWVlNDBhNDYyMGNiMzBiZjdhZGVlMyIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU5MzE3MzA1MSwiZXhwIjoxNTk1NzY1MDUxfQ.42yWHgpXlkPaeNqGNDyPKDAhbtGRz_MYfZrlZP2lF6U"
}
```

Comment: not specified in general graphql, check strapi docs